# Hessian of the distance function--comparison with the space form with constant sectional curvature 0

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curvature

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional complete Riemannian manifold and $r$ is the distance function to a fixed point.

The Hessian comparison theorem says that if the sectional curvature of $M$ is bounded (precisely $k\le \operatorname{sec}\le K$), then the Hessian of $r$ is bounded by the Hessians of the distance function for the space form with constant sectional curvature $k$ and $K$ (precisely $\operatorname{Hess}_Kr\le\operatorname{Hess}r\le \operatorname{Hess}_kr$).

My question: What is the difference between the Hessian of $r$ and the Hessian of the distance function for the space form with constant sectional curvature 0? It's better to have a Taylor expansion.

Following the notation in Petersen's Riemannian geometry, the Hessian of the distance function for the space form with constant sectional curvature $k$ is $\operatorname{Hess}_kr=\frac{\operatorname{sn}_k'(r)}{\operatorname{sn}_k(r)}g_r$ where $g_r=g-(\operatorname{d}r)^2$ and $\frac{\operatorname{sn}_k'(r)}{\operatorname{sn}_k(r)}=\frac{1}{r}-\frac{k}{3}r+O(r^2)$. Note that $\operatorname{Hess}_0r=\frac{1}{r}g_r$. Based on the Hessian comparison theorem, I guess that $\operatorname{Hess}r-\operatorname{Hess}_0r=-\frac{\operatorname{sec}}{3}rg_r+O(r^2)$.

---

I originally guessed that the difference $\operatorname{Hess}r-\operatorname{Hess}_0r$ is a multiplication of the Ricci tensor, big thanks to MySheperd who excluded this possibility and suggested that the difference is $O(r)$ in the answer below. Then I started to ask the above question.

Thank you!

Comment: If $r$ is a distance function both for $g$ and $g_{0}$ (something that in general need not be true), note how $\mathrm{Hess}_{0}\,r\,=\frac{g_{0}-(dr)^{2}}{r}$ in your flat metric $g_{0}$. I think you cannot replace $g_{0}$ with $g$ there.  What I said in my answer below is still valid, I think: in general, the difference $\mathrm{Hess}\,{r}-\mathrm{Hess}_{0}\,r$ will depend on the specfic choice of a flat metric $g_{0}$.

Comment: Please refrain from making substantial changes to your question which may render an answer invalid. I rolled back your question to the original version.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to render the answer invalid. I just wanted to make the question more meaningful.

Comment: @StefanKohl The general idea of my question has never changed. The first few versions are unclear and even the answerer did not see these versions.
I just improved my question to make it concise and clear and even added my new thoughts. I made such a great effort, but you rolled back my question to the origin, it's really unfair.

Comment: @Borromean I merely reacted to a complaint of the answerer. As far as you reach agreement with them, almost anything is fine with me.

Comment: @StefanKohl I have rolled back my question to the latest version without your permission. I think that the answer should be valid for all versions of my question as long as it is correct.

Comment: @Borromean, I wanted to keep this mathematical, but.. you changed your question many times until it transformed from a question about whether the difference of Hessians of a distance function is a multiplication of the Ricci to a question about asymptotic expansions. After I posted my answer, you and I had a discussion in the comments, but you deleted your own comments soon after. Still, I addressed your new question in the comment above, but you are choosing to ignore it and my answer. If you want something different now, then maybe you can open a new question instead of lingering here.

Comment: @MySheperd I never ignored your answer and I appreciate your attempt. I deleted my first guess that the difference is a multiplication of the Ricci tensor before you posted your answer and you had noticed that, so you edited your answer. Yes, I made two comments in your answer: the first one is about Laplacian but I said that the difference for Laplacian is O(1) which is wrong, so I deleted it. The second comment is important and maybe I should not delete it. I said that the space form is different from $M$ while you are considering two metrics both on $M$.

Comment: @MySheperd Your answer contains some correct facts and I was the first one to vote it up. But I think that your answer is not correct in general, at least it does not get the point of my question.

Comment: You did not document any changes you made to the original question. You started asking about asymptotic expansions only after I noted that the difference can be $o(r)$ in general, and only after we had a further discussion about this in the comments . Even if you get another idea from an answer, and realize your original question does not fit into exactly what you are looking for, it does not mean you need to change your question entirely to fit this new idea --- rendering previous answers invalid, as @StefanKohl put it. I think the right thing to do in this case is to open a new question.

Comment: In any event, I again bring to your attention that a distance function $r$ for a metric $g$ is in general not a distance function for a different metric $g_{0}$. Even if it is, and we write $g=dr^{2}+g_{r}$ and $g_{0}=dr^{2}+g^{0}_{r}$, note how $g_{r}$ is different than $g^{0}_{r}$. Thus, if the metric $g_{0}$ is flat, it is incorrect that $\mathrm{Hess}_{0}\,r=\frac{1}{r}g_{r}$, but rather $\mathrm{Hess}_{0}\,r=\frac{1}{r}\,g^{0}_{r}$. Again we find that $\mathrm{Hess}\,r-\mathrm{Hess}_{0}\,r$ depends on the exact choice of metrics $g$ and $g_{0}$, just like the original answer.

Comment: Now that you are so confirming that your answer is correct, why do you prevent the latest version of my question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136011/discussion-between-mysheperd-and-borromean).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$dr$ is defined regardless of the metric. If $g$ and $g_{0}$ are two metrics, and $\nabla^{g}$ and $\nabla^{g_{0}}$ are their corresponding Levi-Civita connections, then the connection difference yields a tensorial operation $D:T^*M\rightarrow T^*{}M\otimes T^{*}M$ such that $\mathrm{Hess}\,r-\mathrm{Hess}_{0}\,r=\nabla^{g}dr-\nabla^{g_{0}}dr=D(dr)$. If one now assumes that $g_{0}$ is locally-flat, i.e., that its curvature tensor has 0-constant sectional cruvature, then one can pick parallel coordinates for this metric which makes $(\nabla^{g_{0}}dr)_{ij}=\partial_{i}\partial_{j}r$. Therefore, in these coordiantes $D(dr)_{ij}=-\Gamma_{ij}^{k}\partial_{k}r$, where $\Gamma_{ij}^{k}$ are the chirstoffel symbols of the metric $g$. This includes only first derivatives of the metric, hence in general it won't be e.g. a multipication of the Ricci-Tensor.

In fact, if one picks $r$ to be a distance function, and picks polar coordinates with respect to this function, then an example of a locally-flat metric is $g_{0}=dr\otimes dr+\sum_{i=1}^{d-1}dx_{i}\otimes dx_{i}$. These polar coordinates are then parallel coordinates for $g_{0}$, and $D(dr)_{ij}=-\delta_{k}^{r}\Gamma_{ij}^{k}$. Since in polar coordinates $\Gamma_{ij}^{k}=o(r)$, this would imply that the difference vanishes as r goes to zero. This example also shows that the expression would depend on the choice of the particular locally-flat metric $g_{0}$.

---

**Edit:** Regarding @Borromean follow up question, the difference does not have to be $o(r)$ either. Let us take a unit disc $\mathcal{D}\subset \mathbb{R^{2}}$ and pick for it the usual polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$. Write two different metrics: $g=dr\otimes dr+r^{2}d\theta\otimes d\theta$ and $g_{0}=d\theta\otimes d\theta+\theta^{2}dr\otimes dr$. Note how both of these metrics are flat: they are simply eucliden metrics written in polar coordinates, with the roles of $r$ and $\theta$ exchanged. As such, both have constant sectional curvature 0. Note how $r$ is a distance function in one metric but not in the other.

However, $\mathrm{Hess}\,r=\nabla^{g} dr=-\Gamma_{\theta\theta}^{r}d\theta\,\otimes d\theta=-\frac{1}{r} d\theta\,\otimes d\theta$ while $\mathrm{Hess}_{0}r=\nabla^{g_{0}}dr=-\frac{1}{\theta}(dr\otimes d\theta+d\theta\otimes dr)$. So in this case, the difference will explode as $r\rightarrow 0$. Moreover, since the curvature of both metrics vanishes, the coefficents in the expansion of this difference in either $r$ or $\theta$ will include no expressions involving the curvature, as all curvature ingredients vanish identically.

Comment: In polar coordinates $g^{ij}=\delta^{ij}+o(r^2)$ so in this example we still have $\Delta r-\Delta_{0}r=-g^{ij}\Gamma_{ij}^{r}=o(r)$. In general, if the Hessian vanishes identitacly so must the Laplacian.

Comment: I forgot to note how $\Delta_{0}r=0$ in the polar coordinates, when we are using the locally flat metric $g_{0}$. This is becuase $\partial_{i}\partial_{j}r=0$ and the christoffel symbols of this metric in these coordinates vanish identically.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand correctly your question, but I think there is no escape from this, since in order to discuss the expression $\mathrm{Hess}\,r-\mathrm{Hess}_{0}\,r$, both of these objects must be sections of $T^{*}M\otimes T^{*}M$. Even if you take another space of constant sectional curvature 0, say $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, and map a neighborhood in it locally to a neighborhood in $M$ where $r$ is defined, this is where this difference is understood. Every such a map will induce, by declaration, a different flat metric on that neighborhood by pulling back the euclidean metric.

Comment: Did you read the Hessian comparison theorem? The metrics are on different manifolds and the distance functions are also on different manifolds. When we compare the Hessians, we take the distance functions to be both $r$. Did you read the page 175 of the 2nd edition of Petersen's Riemannian geometry? It says that the difference is $O(r)$.

Comment: The Hessians are defined on different tangent bundles, see Theorem 1.1 of Schoen-Yau's lectures on differential geometry.

Comment: @Borromean, there its the same manifold, simply locally diffeomorphic around $p$ to an open set in $(0,\infty)\times S^{n-1}$ by using polar coordinates for $r$. The fact that you make the comparison $\mathrm{Hess}\,r-\mathrm{Hess}_{0}\,r$ locally in $M$ or in a manifold diffeomorphic to it doesn't matter. Different metrics will assume different forms under this diffeomorphism, however, as is the situation in my answer. Are you looking for the comparison when you pick the specific flat metric $g_{0}=dr\otimes dr+r^{2}ds^{2}_{n-1}$ defined on $(0,\infty)\times S^{n-1}$ and pulled back to $M$?

Comment: Yes, your $g_0$ should be that.

Comment: $r$ should be the distance function for both $g$ and $g_0$.

Comment: Sorry, I finally realized that the difference should depend on the choice of $g_0$ and this question is not what I intend to ask.

Comment: I asked a new question.