# Asymptotic expansion of the Hessian of the distance function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curvature

This question originates from [another question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421106/hessian-of-the-distance-function-comparison-with-the-space-form-with-constant-s?noredirect=1#comment1082766_421106). Big thanks to MySheperd whose answer to that question clarified my thoughts.

Let $(M,g)$ be an $n$-dimensional complete Riemannian manifold and $r$ is the distance function to a fixed point.

My question: What is the asymptotic expansion of the Hessian of $r$?

On page 175 of the 2nd edition of Petersen's Riemannian geometry, it wrote that $\operatorname{Hess}r=\frac{g_r}{r}+O(r)$ where $g_r=g-(\operatorname{d}r)^2$. I would like to know the next terms in the Taylor expansion of $O(r)$. Since they are invariant, they can only depend on the curvature and covariant derivatives of the curvature.

Thank you!

Comment: One approach is roughly the following: Let $H$ be the Hessian of $r$. Fix an orthonormal frame $(e_1, \dots, e_n)$, where $e_n$ is radial, that is parallel along radial geodesics and let $A_{jk} = H(e_j,e_k)$. Then it can be shown, using Jacobi fields, that $$ A' + A^2 + K = 0, $$ where $K_{jk} = R_{jnkn}$ and $$ A \simeq \frac{\delta}{r}. $$ You can now write $A  = \frac{\delta}{r} + A_0 + A_1r +\cdots$ and solve recursively for $A_k$.

Comment: The matrix Riccati equation above is derived in this note: https://www.math.toronto.edu/~vtk/eschenburg-comparison.pdf

Comment: Actually, you would expand the series in terms of powers of the exponential coordinates $(x^1, \cdots, x^n)$ and not just $r$.

Comment: @DeaneYang Thanks! Your comments are helpful, I will try.